# How to write separate log files for separate services in dionaea honeypot

Tags: logging, honeypot

I am trying to set up a honeypot service on the network and I installed dionaea honeypot. I figured out that each service is being controlled by yaml files present in `/opt/dionaea/etc/dionaea/services-available`.

The way defaults work is all the logs are being written to `/opt/dionaea/var/log/dionaea/dionaea.log` file.

How do I set it up so that each service writes to its own file so that I can have separate files for separate services? A typical yaml file present in dionaea's service-available looks like below.

```
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: none
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

- name: ftp
  config:
    root: "var/lib/dionaea/ftp/root"
    response_messages:
      welcome_msg: 220 DiskStation FTP server ready.
```

Comment: Why do you want separate files? Why not filter the main log file? and did you read the manual about what logging is for? https://dionaea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#logging

Comment: My idea is to send it to an external SIEM. keeping all the services writing to different files helps me upload the data easier. Currently i have to write additional routing to make sure data gets to the right location.

Comment: And did you read the manual? They have a lot to say about their logging. (and especially about logging to files)